# For a given holomorphic $f$ how can we find $f(-i)$ when $f\left( \dfrac{1}{n} +i \dfrac{1}{n^2} \right) = \dfrac{n^2}{n+(1+2n^2)i}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can we show using tools from complex analysis that from $f: D(0,2) \to \mathbb{C}$
\begin{align}
f\left( \dfrac{1}{n} +i \dfrac{1}{n^2} \right) = \dfrac{n^2}{n+(1+2n^2)i}
\end{align}
we can find the value $f(-i)$?

Obvious algebra does not cut it. How can we proceed?

I sense that I have to use something like the Uniqueness Theorem but I cannot comprehend it yet.

Comment: Find a homorphic function satisfying the propery you mentioned. By the identity theorem it is unquie, since the sequence as an accumulation point in the disk with radius $2$ (In other words: the sequence you are looking at is not discrete).
Then proceed to compute $f(-i)$ by just plugging in.

Comment: I am really stumped about this, can you give me a further hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac1n + \frac i{n^2} = -i \implies n^2 - in + 1 = 0 \implies n = i \frac{1\pm\sqrt5}2$$

Replacing $n$ accordingly, we find $f(-i) = -i$ for either choice of $n$.

Answer (score 3):

The (unique) such function is $f(z)=\frac1{z+2i}$, and $f(-i)=\frac1{-i+2i}=-i.$

Comment: I found $f$ by chance, noting that $\dfrac{n^2}{n+(1+2n^2)i}=\dfrac1{\frac{n+i}{n^2}+2i}.$